# Autowired DAO object is null Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, dao

I'm programming a rest service that can access to a database to see, add and update fields from a mysql table. I've implemented this with Spring Boot.

The fact is, when I'm trying to autowire the DAO object it won't work, is null, so my application always throws a NullPointerException.

This is my application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.setoncios.api")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.setoncios.api.dao.workers.WorkerDAO.java")
public class GenericApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GenericApiApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket swaggerSettings() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .pathMapping("/");
    }
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

Here is my DAO implementation:

```
@Component
public interface WorkerDAO extends CrudRepository<Persona,String>{

}
```

The rest method that contains the method throwing the exception:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/worker", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> addWorkerInDatabase(HttpServletRequest request,
        @RequestParam(value = "json", defaultValue = 
        "{\"dni\":\"00000000A\",\"nombre\":\"Paco\",\"apellido1\":\"Ruiz\",\"apellido2\":\"Díaz\"}") final String json){
    ProcessAction object = new AddWorkerInDatabaseAction(request, json);
    return object.createResponse();
}
```

And the class itself:

```
public class AddWorkerInDatabaseAction extends ProcessAction{
private String json;

@Autowired
private UserDatabase userDb = new UserDatabase();

@Autowired
private WorkerDAO workDb;

public AddWorkerInDatabaseAction(HttpServletRequest request, String json) {
    super(request);
    this.json = json;
}

@Override
protected Object action() throws ExpectedException {
    Persona newWorker = new Gson().fromJson(json, Persona.class);
    Cookie c = findCookie("userdata");
    String[] loggedUser = null;

    if(newWorker == null){
        LOGGER.warning("Unable to decrypt from json to Persona.");

    } else if(c == null){
        LOGGER.info("Couldn't find cookie. Unable to add a worker.");
        newWorker = null;

    } else {            
        try {
            userDb.connect();

            loggedUser = c.getValue().split(":");

            if(!loggedUser[0].equals("00000000A") || !loggedUser[1].equals(userDb.selectPassword("00000000A"))){
                LOGGER.warning("You need privileges to add a worker.");

            } else if(newWorker.getNombre() == null || newWorker.getApellido1() == null || newWorker.getApellido2() == null){
                workDb.save(newWorker); //Here's where the exception is being thrown. 

            } else {
                workDb.save(newWorker); //Here's where the exception is being thrown. 
            }


        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            userDb.rollback();
            newWorker = null;
            LOGGER.warning("Exception with driver encountered.");
            throw new ExpectedException(1, e.getMessage());

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            userDb.rollback();
            newWorker = null;
            throw new ExpectedException(2, e.getMessage());

        } finally {
            userDb.commit();
            userDb.disconnect();
        }
    }


    return newWorker;
}

}
```

I've read through lots of posts, but I won't found a way that it works. Is there an annotation that I missed to write?

Thank you in advance :3

Edit. After applying the answer, my main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.setoncios.api")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.setoncios.api.dao.workers")
public class GenericApiApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(GenericApiApplication.class, args);
}

@Bean
public Docket swaggerSettings() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .pathMapping("/");
}
```

}

The rest method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/worker", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> addWorkerInDatabase(HttpServletRequest request,
        @RequestParam(value = "json", defaultValue = 
        "{\"dni\":\"00000000A\",\"nombre\":\"Paco\",\"apellido1\":\"Ruiz\",\"apellido2\":\"Díaz\"}") final String json){
    return addDB.createResponse(request, json);
}
```

And the AddWorkerInDatabaseAction class:

```
@Service
public class AddWorkerInDatabaseAction extends ProcessAction{
@Autowired
private UserDatabase userDb = new UserDatabase();

@Autowired
private WorkerDAO workDb;

public AddWorkerInDatabaseAction() {
}

@Override
protected Object action(Object...args) throws ExpectedException {
    Persona newWorker = new Gson().fromJson((String) args[1], Persona.class);
    workDb.save(newWorker);


    return newWorker;
}

}
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: you shouldn't create object of `AddWorkerInDatabaseAction` class with `new` operator, you should autowire it instead.

Comment: I had it that way because there are more actions that comes from ProcessAction. That way I tried to diferenciate them. I'll try to find other way to improve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the `AddWorkerInDatabaseAction` class a Spring Service. Also instead of passing the arguments to constructor, you can pass them to the actual method directly.

```
 @Service
 public class AddWorkerInDatabaseAction extends ProcessAction{
     .....

     protected Object action(HttpServletRequest request, String json) throws ExpectedException {
     .....
 }
```

In your controller, you can autowire the bean of this class which spring creates,

```
 private class MyController{

     @Autowire
     ProcessAction object;

     @RequestMapping(value = "/worker", method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public ResponseEntity<?> addWorkerInDatabase(HttpServletRequest request,
             @RequestParam(value = "json", defaultValue = 
    "{\"dni\":\"00000000A\",\"nombre\":\"Paco\",\"apellido1\":\"Ruiz\",\"apellido2\":\"Díaz\"}") final String json){
         return object.createResponse(request, json);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it seems that it needed some more wiring to finally work out. I'll edit my post with my post code.

Answer (score 1):

I think possibly your annotation

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.setoncios.api.dao.workers.WorkerDAO.java")
```

is wrong. The default value for this annotation is a base package to scan for annotated classes. So in your case it should be `"com.setoncios.api.dao.workers"`.

There is also a `basePackageClasses` which you can set to get more type safety and then you can just point it to the `WorkerDAO.class`

Also as the other answer suggests you should make `AddWorkerInDatabaseAction` a service and autowire that in your controller. That way spring will inject the necessary beans.

Comment: The annotation change was also wrong, it should signal to a package. Changing it to '"com.setoncios.api.dao.workers"' worked well.